# Лишний байт при записи структуры в файл

Tags: c++, c, файлы, вывод, запись

Откуда берется лишний байт?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct {
    int a;
    float b;
} structEx;
#pragma pack(pop)
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    {
        structEx x;
        x.a = 2;
        x.b = 4.2;
        ofstream fout("Text1.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            x.a += 3;
            x.b += 0.5;
            fout.write((char *)&x, sizeof(x));
        }
        fout.close();
    }
    {
        structEx x;
        x.a = 2;
        x.b = 4.2;
        ofstream fout("Text2.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            x.a += 3;
            x.b += 0.51;
            fout.write((char *)&x, sizeof(x));
        }
        fout.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Text1.txt при `x.b += 0.5;`

```
// 0500 0000 6666 9640 0800 0000 6666 a640
// 0b00 0000 6666 b640 0e00 0000 6666 c640
// 1100 0000 6666 d640 1400 0000 6666 e640
// 1700 0000 6666 f640 1a00 0000 3333 0341
// 1d00 0000 3333 0b41 2000 0000 3333 1341
```

Text2.txt при `x.b += 0.51;`

```
// 0500 0000 52b8 9640 0800 0000 3e0d 0aa7
// 400b 0000 002a 5cb7 400e 0000 0016 aec7
// 4011 0000 0002 00d8 4014 0000 00ee 51e8
// 4017 0000 00da a3f8 401a 0000 00e3 7a04
// 411d 0000 00d9 a30c 4120 0000 00cf cc14
// 41
```

Comment: Открывайте  `ofstream fout("Text.txt");` в бинарном режиме.

Comment: А как этот код у вас вообще компилируется?... Все же нужно - если вопрос идет о времени выполнения - давать рабочий код.

Comment: Программа записывает в файл байты. Потом ручками открываю файл в бинарном режиме и вижу лишний байт! ЗЫ Код подправил, сейчас должно компилиться

Comment: Я вижу, что она записывает. Еще раз и медленно - открывайте файл так, как я написал в моем ответе. Обратите внимание в своем файле на "сладкую парочку" - `0d 0a` - там явно должен быть только один `0a`.

Comment: связанный вопрос [why when we write \n in the file it converts into \r\n combination?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19839883/4279)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

По умолчанию потоки открываются в текстовом режиме (при котором символ `\n` преобразуется в Windows в пару `\r\n`), так что надо просто вместо

```
ofstream fout("Text.txt");
```

написать

```
ofstream fout("Text.txt", ios::binary);
```

Компьютер не понимает разницы между бинарными и текстовыми данными - для него все это один поток байтов, а что они означают - ему безразлично. Когда вы открываете файл для записи в текстовом режиме в соответствующей операционной системе, это означает команду *"пиши байты как есть, но если встретишь байт `0x0A` - запиши пару `0x0D 0x0A`"*. А при чтении - наоборот - *"если встретишь эту пару байт - то в память заноси только один `0x0A`"*.

Comment: так почему лишний байт? почему только один лишний байт?

Comment: потому что каждый символ '\n' записывается как два байта, но Вы ожидаете 1. два минус один как раз и равно одному лишнему байту.

Comment: @KtoTo: посмотрите на 0d 0a в `Text2.txt`. Структура содержит 0a, но так как вы пишите в текстовом режиме, то 0a на 0d 0a на Windows заменяется. Никогда не пишите двоичные данные в текстовом режиме. Для ясности, не используйте `.txt` расширение в этом случае.

Comment: @KtoTo Вам не обязательно его писать "явно". Меняется именно байт на два.

Comment: Компьютер не понимает разницы между бинарными и текстовыми данными - для него все это один поток байтов, а что они означают - ему безразлично. Когда вы открываете файл для записи в текстовом режиме в соответствующей операционной системе, это означает команду "пиши байты как есть, но если встретишь байт 0x0A - запиши пару 0x0D 0x0A". А при чтении - наоборот - "если встретишь эту пару байт - то в память заноси только один 0x0A".

Comment: @Harry зачем он (Уиндоус) так делает интересно?

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Это не он делает :) А вообще - тяжкое наследие CP/M, через DOS пришедшее в Windows. Здесь принят конец строки `\r\n` в текстовом файле. В *nix - просто `\n`. Могу ошибаться, но вроде на Маках было `\r` - но здесь я совсем не уверен, я с ними дела не имел. Причем под DOS'ом реально *nix-овые файлы при выводе выводились "лесенкой" - с переходом на новую строку (`\n`), но без возврата к началу (`\r`).

Comment: @Harry, на маках раньше было, но сейчас они передумали :)

Comment: @Qwertiy Я верно понимаю, что сначала там был "чисто конкретно" Mac (ну, совсем отдельная разработка), а теперь - клон *nix?

Answer (score 0):

Под операционной системой `Linux` данный код выполняется корректно и не производит добавление лишних байт в файл.

```
root@debian:/# g++ 1.cpp
root@debian:/# ./a.out
root@debian:/# hexdump -C Text1.txt
00000000  05 00 00 00 66 66 96 40  08 00 00 00 66 66 a6 40  |....ff.@....ff.@|
00000010  0b 00 00 00 66 66 b6 40  0e 00 00 00 66 66 c6 40  |....ff.@....ff.@|
00000020  11 00 00 00 66 66 d6 40  14 00 00 00 66 66 e6 40  |....ff.@....ff.@|
00000030  17 00 00 00 66 66 f6 40  1a 00 00 00 33 33 03 41  |....ff.@....33.A|
00000040  1d 00 00 00 33 33 0b 41  20 00 00 00 33 33 13 41  |....33.A ...33.A|
00000050
root@debian:/# hexdump -C Text2.txt
00000000  05 00 00 00 52 b8 96 40  08 00 00 00 3e 0a a7 40  |....R..@....>..@|
00000010  0b 00 00 00 2a 5c b7 40  0e 00 00 00 16 ae c7 40  |....*\.@.......@|
00000020  11 00 00 00 02 00 d8 40  14 00 00 00 ee 51 e8 40  |.......@.....Q.@|
00000030  17 00 00 00 da a3 f8 40  1a 00 00 00 e3 7a 04 41  |.......@.....z.A|
00000040  1d 00 00 00 d9 a3 0c 41  20 00 00 00 cf cc 14 41  |.......A ......A|
00000050
```

Как уже ответили, проблема происходит под некоторыми устаревшими операционными системами, сам же код ошибки не содержит. Не ищите ошибку там, где ее нет.

Comment: устаревшие ОС это вин10?) Я понял, что виндоз самоправно что то(при 0х0А) добавляет, если файл записывается как текстовый.

Comment: Просто в Linux перевод строки одним байтом производится, а, например, в Windows, Symbian OS - двумя.

Comment: @KtoTo не "виндоз", а стандартная библиотека с++, запущенная под ней.